# I need to populate the value of a text field

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

The *value* of `universal_leadid` is populated on every refresh and it come from a script related to a 3rd party Lead verification service (*leadid.com*). The objective for me is to post the `other6` field *value* the same as the *value* assosiated with `universal_leadid` field.

HTML:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Other6" value="">
<input type="hidden" name="universal_leadid" value="KFLS00-D254-DD521-GF52-GHT554125" id="leadid_token">
```

Lead Id *value* is populated by lead id but I can't get *value* of the `Other6` field.

This is what I have tried and the result is blank or nothing:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('[name=Other6]').val($('[name=universal_leadid]').val()); 
    //alert(universal_leadid);
    //console.log($('[name=universal_leadid]'));
    //console.log($('[name=universal_leadid]').val());
    //console.log($('[name=Other6]').val());
    $('#salutation').attr('checked',false); 

    //var myValue = $( "#leadid_token" ).val();
    //document.getElementById('leadid_token');
    //var x = document.getElementById("leadid_token").value;
    //alert(x); // Showing Empty alert box 

});
```

The result I want, is that every *value* populated on `universal_leadid` need to go to `Other6` field

Comment: Have you include `jQuery` file?

Comment: Yes its all set and this is First time happening

Comment: This seems to to work fine when I run it, or do you want this to happen everything the value in universal_leadid changes ?

Comment: Please, include any errors and include your (non)working code in a minimal example. Why have you included all of the commented lines?

Comment: i know this works for me with any other field, that's why i posted it here, so i said maybe because the lead id value is not a fix value and its coming from a lead it website and i need to duplicate that value into an other field

Comment: @Bill , **Where** are you expecting to see the values?

Comment: am expecting something like this :
<input type="text" name="Other6" value="KFLS00-D254-DD521-GF52-GHT554125">
<input type="text" name="universal_leadid" value="KFLS00-D254-DD521-GF52-GHT554125" id="leadid_token">

Comment: Then your code works just perfectly - http://jsfiddle.net/q4pf3hpL/

Comment: for Static value yes but for a value witch load on each refresh that doesn't work for me so do you know how i can do it somehow

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand :(

Comment: We need the full picture. What do you do, when and why. We already have answered your question given the elements you provided. Please edit your question and describe a full scenario so we can give you a more exhaustive answer.

Comment: How and when do you exactly set (populate) the `universal_leadid` field value? Perhaps it's still empty at the time when you try to copy its value into `Other6` field? Post the code sample.

Comment: Did you know that normally a question has a question mark in it? And your question title is awful, it provides no assistance to future users trying to find a solution to their own problem that might be similar, but they will never know, because your title is so incredibly vague.

Comment: don't bother yourself then and keep your comment

Answer (score 1):

Your both the `input` fields are `hidden`

Please use

```
<input type="text" name="Other6" value="">
<input type="text" name="universal_leadid" value="KFLS00-D254-DD521-GF52-GHT554125" id="leadid_token">
```

**Working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4d4waLk7/)**

Comment: the field should be hidden

Comment: Then what are you expecting on your display?

Comment: am expecting when i validate the form, the Other 6 take the value of lead_id

Comment: Yes Bill, But as you can see they (input) are getting the values, doesnt matter they are hidden or not.

Comment: i know but i want the other 6 to take the same Value ad universal_leadid and its not working for me that what drove me crazy lol

Comment: Why dont you gave me the code of that?

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
var token = $("#leadid_token").val();
$("input[name=Other6]").val(token);
console.log($("input[name=Other6]").val());
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8rw9cep6/

Comment: This is showing me the same thing with my original code :
Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience.

Comment: this error is because you are using somewhere an synchronous XMLHttpRequests. This is not related to that part of the code. Do you have any ajax call ?

Comment: The leadid_token Value is populated based on a scrip witch generate that value on each "Reload" so the value is not static on the form its changing on each "Refresh"
 i was thinking about php if i can use the explode string and then copy the posted value and paste it to the field Other 6

Comment: Please edit your question with that script, almost certain that the solution is in there.